# Constraints in Xcode 8 - Making an object enlarge depending on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, xcode8

I really struggle with constraints for some reason. I'm attempting to get this object in the middle to expand. In the first image thats what I want it to look like on all devices. What constraints would I need to apply so it can expand depending on the size of the device

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what constraints are you using now? You'd likely just need a leading/trailing without a width constraint, for the width to "magically" adjust to any width.

Comment: Not using any at the moment because I have no idea how to achieve what I'm trying to do. I'll try out leading/trailing.

Comment: Yea, so in general you'll want 4 constraints, and with what you're looking to do, looks like you'd want: top/height/leading/trailing. You usually, in the autolayout world, want to stay away from "hard coded" width/heights, but depends on the UI component...

Comment: I've got most of it working fine, but I have got one UImageView which isn't centered and I can't seem to get it to work with all views. I'll post an image of what I'm trying to do in the original post.

Comment: that image view is a subview of the text container? or how is that structured? And you're talking about centering x, or centering y? Judging just from your screen grabs, I'd imagine you have a UIView with a UILabel and a UIImageView inside of it. To accomplish vertical centering within the UIView, you'd just add a centerY constraint, along with a leading constraint (from imageView to label).

Comment: Sorry, should have put more detail into it. The overlay is a separate UIImageView and the text is a separate UIlabel. The image to the side is also a separate UIImageView and I would like it to stay the same size with the same distance from the text label to the image and the right margin to the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your comment, with the view structure you have, it's going to be hard to keep "the same distance from the text label".

I would suggest this:

```
UIView (root view for this view)

  UIImageView (your overlay, which should have top/bottom/left/right constraints to edges)

  UIView (a container view, which will hold the label and arrow image. This should have, as we discussed, top/height/left/right constraints)

      UILabel (label for your text, centered horizontally within it's superview container, as well as vertically)

      UIImageView (arrow, with a leading constraint pinned to the right of the label, and with centered vertically constraint to it's superview)
```

This should achieve what you're after, I believe. Also, when I say left/right, that is synonymous with leading/trailing.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I feel a lot more familiar with constraints in Xcode now, thanks again.